# Initialization script on Elastic Beanstalk instances

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have in AWS some instances that are managed by Beanstalk. But I need to include a script in these instances so that as soon as it gets terminate and rebooted again it runs my script. Where and how can I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.ebextensions might be what you're looking for. You can set up ebextensions config files to do a lot of things, from package installs and placing files in place to raw bash commands.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html?shortFooter=true
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html?shortFooter=true

Comment: Perfect! in the end it was simpler than I imagined ... thank you very much.